# Combining cell text based on a date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

Trying to get rows on Master sheet to combine into single cells on 2nd Sheet based on which date range they fall into.

Here's the [example sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i1GPk9L7OCMtds1mIdW-5ZIit-PwqU_4uX0iLsLNSnc/edit?usp=sharing)

I've got some attempts and then an example of what product I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification? In this modification, `TO_DATE` is used for your formula

#### Modified formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",true,ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(if(Master!$B$2:$B < $C2,Master!$B$2:$D,""))))
```

#### Result:

When above modified formula is used, the following result is obtained.

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [TO_DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239)